# expl3 in package

Tags: expl3, package-writing, package-options, l3keys

I've read in `interface3.pdf` that `expl3` is natively supported in LaTeX2e since February 2020. However, I cannot make the following work:

```latex
% test.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{test}

\DeclareKeys{
    lang.choices:nn = {uk, de}{
        \newcommand{\lang}{\ExplSyntaxOn\int_use:N\l_keys_choice_int\ExplSyntaxOff}
    }
}

\ProcessKeyOptions\relax
```

```latex
% test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lang=de]{test}

\begin{document}

\lang

\end{document}
```

In the end, I only get an integral symbol printed and letters, some in subscript, as if in math mode. What am I doing wrong? Wrapping in `\ExplSyntaxOn ... \ExplSyntaxOff` around the definition inside `\newcommand` does not help.

[image]

Comment: When using `l3keys`, use `\keys_define:` not `\DeclareKeys`. Also you need `\ProvidesPackage` or perhaps `\ProvidesExplPackage` not `\ProvidesClass`. Also "In the end, I only get an integral symbol printed and letters, some in lowercase, as if in math mode." needs an example code for clarity, which your MWE doesn't provide.

Comment: @User23456234 You're right, I meant to write `\ProvidesPackage`. Nonetheless, the MWE is an example code. I added a screenshot.

Comment: your example is incomplete. That gives no output at all. Make a real example, not some fake. And naturally you need \ExplSyntaxOn if you use commands like `\int_use:N`.

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks `\int_use:N\l_keys_choice_int` is being turned into an integral starting with `\int_u`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're completely right, my bad (the file was an old one from previous trials). I updated it accordingly.

Comment: \ExplSyntaxOn must be before the \DeclareKeys not inside (and \ExplSyntaxOff behind. )

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This solves the problem. However, I thought that I do not need this if I'm writing a package, similar to `\makeatother`?

Comment: If you need `\ProvidesExplPackage {package} {date} {version}{ description}` if you want expl3-syntax on automatically.